# An API (FastAPI & Azure function) endpoint with content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working when deployed in app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, fastapi, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans

I have an azure function that usages fast api. When api is deployed in serverless plan, all endpoint works perfectly. **However, when it's deployed in app service plan a login endpoint, when requested from front-end  shows 422 (entity not processed) but works when requested from api doc"domain/doc".  The endpoint accepts a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. All of the other endpoint also work when requested from the front-end.**

This is the source code for the front-end application

```
const formData = new URLSearchParams();
  formData.append("username", username);
  formData.append("password", password);
  console.log(formData.toString())
  const response = await fetchClient.post<Token>(
    "/v1/login",
    formData.toString(),
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    }
  );
```

- I have confirmed that both application have exactly same configuration

**The issue has been resolve by using / at the end of the each request**

Comment: Could you provide the full code of how you're calling the fast API from the Azure function code?

Comment: @Yugesh try using `const formData = new FormData();` and in place of `formData.toString()` use `body : form Data,`

Comment: Thanks @VivekVaibhavShandilya, however the above script and your suggestion are same.

Comment: @DasariKamali this is the sample source code https://github.com/yugyesh/fast-api-azure-function.

Comment: @Yugesh - Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

- I have resolved this issue by using / at the end of the each request. I am not certain about the cause.